# Insert binary std::string using ODBC into BLOB column

Tags: blob, binary-data, insert-update

can somebody give me an example how to insert binary std::string using ODBC and C++ into BLOB column, please?

EDIT:

Duplicate of [How to INSERT binary std::string into BLOB (MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733262/how-to-insert-binary-stdstring-into-blob-mysql).

Comment: Looks like a dup: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733262/how-to-insert-binary-stdstring-into-blob-mysql>

Comment: From the same person, no less

Comment: Yes, but there is no real answer as well...

Comment: Then in that case, maybe you need should post a bounty for the original question? Also, you have not really succeeded in explaining why the answer to the original question was wrong.

Comment: Hope now I done in the original question comment....

Comment: I've updated the original with a link to the MySQL man page on parameter binding

Comment: I have asked NOT TO USE MySQL staff like 'mysql_real_escape_string' etc. to have this generic but you are doing just opposite

Comment: Your original question explicitly asked about MySQL. I can't be bothered answering questions from people who can't make up their mind what they are asking about. Bye.

Comment: This is from my original question: "I do not want to use mysql_real_escape_string staff because i want to keep it not only for MySQL"

Comment: This is probably the solution I am looking for: http://lists.mysql.com/plusplus/1546?f=plain (void DatenbankMySQL::escape_blob (std::string& s) ) Do you think this will work?

Answer (score 0):

If it is really a binary string, and you have actual binary data in it (e.g. embedded nulls) then you need to be careful not to use any of the std::string members that can treat it as a C string (e.g. with a terminating null) as you will obviously end up losing data.

The `std::string` class is not really appropriate for this purpose - it is written on the assumption that what you are working with is actually a string of characters - since you are using a blob or array of binary data, a `std::vector` is probably more appropriate.

To insert the data will require you to bind the content of the vector to the SQL query using bind parameters. That is to say, instead of using [SQLExecDirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713611(VS.85).aspx) to execute a string containing the SQL query, you should use [SQLPrepare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710926(VS.85).aspx) to create the statement handle - you leave the spot where the value of the binary value would go with a '?', then use [SQLBindParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710963(VS.85).aspx) to bind the placeholder to the binary value. You then call the function using [SQLExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713584(VS.85).aspx).

There are some code examples in the `SQLBindParameter` documentation above.

Comment: This is probably the solution I am looking for:
http://lists.mysql.com/plusplus/1546?f=plain
(void DatenbankMySQL::escape_blob (std::string& s) )
Do you think this will work?

Comment: Then please ignore my rantings about using or not using std::string with binary data and focus on the details of using bind parameters