# StreamTransformationFilter: ciphertext length is not a multiple of block size?

Tags: c++, mysql, encryption, cryptography, crypto++

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt a plain text using aes algorithm present in [crypto++](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp)

Here is my encryption method

```
/*
 * Encrypt the given text
 */

template<typename T>
T encryptText(T plainText) {
    /* Key and IV setup
     * AES encryption uses a secret key of a variable length (128-bit, 196-bit or 256-   
     * bit). This key is secretly exchanged between two parties before communication   
     * begins. DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH= 16 bytes
     */
    byte key[ CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH ], iv[ CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE ];
    memset( key, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH );
    memset( iv, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE );
    T cipherText;
    cout << "\n\nPlain Text size is (" << plainText.size() << " bytes)" << "\n\n";
    cout << plainText << "\n\n";
    /*
     * Create Cipher Text
     */
    CryptoPP::AES::Encryption aesEncryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption( aesEncryption, iv );
    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink( cipherText ) );
    stfEncryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( plainText.c_str() ), plainText.length() + 1 );
    stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();
    cout << "\n\nCipher Text size is (" << cipherText.size() << " bytes)" << std::endl;
    for( int i = 0; i < cipherText.size(); i++ ) {
        cout << "0x" << std::hex << (0xFF & static_cast<byte>(cipherText[i])) << " ";
    }
    return cipherText;
}
```

Here is my decryption method

```
/*
 * Decrypt the given text
 */

template<typename T>
T decryptText(T encryptedText) {
    /* Key and IV setup
     * AES encryption uses a secret key of a variable length (128-bit, 196-bit or 256-   
     * bit). This key is secretly exchanged between two parties before communication   
     * begins. DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH= 16 bytes
     */
    byte key[ CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH ], iv[ CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE ];
    memset( key, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH );
    memset( iv, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE );
    CryptoPP::AES::Decryption aesDecryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption cbcDecryption( aesDecryption, iv );
    T decryptedText;
    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfDecryptor(cbcDecryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink( decryptedText ) );
    stfDecryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( encryptedText.c_str() ), encryptedText.size() );
    stfDecryptor.MessageEnd();
    std::cout << "\n\nDecrypted Text is " << "\n\n";
    std::cout << "\n\n" << decryptedText << "\n\n";
    return decryptedText;
}
```

`encryptText` function execute normally and i save the output of it in mysql database. While calling the `decryptText` function an error occurs saying

```
An uncaught exception occurred: StreamTransformationFilter: ciphertext length is not a multiple of block size
```

And i understand that this error is because of encrypted text may contain some null(0) value too. How decrypt the actual text.

**Edit :**

As i asked to show my sql queries in comment section.

Here is my sql query to fetch the saved encrypted data in mysql database.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void getUserSms(T1 userId,vector<T1>& smsIds,vector<T2>& text){
    try{
        mysql::connection db_cs(config_cs_db());
        auto sms = db_cs.run(select(all_of(us)).from(us).where(us.usersUserId == userId));
        while(!sms.empty()){
            const auto& row = sms.front();
            auto smsId = row.id.value();
            smsIds.push_back(smsId);
            auto encryptedText = row.text.value();
            auto plainText = decryptText(encryptedText);
            text.push_back(plainText);
            sms.pop_front();
        }
        return;
    }
    catch (const sqlpp::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Could not get user sms due to some reason ...!!\n";
        std:cerr << e.what() << "\n";
        return;
    }
}
```

I am using [sqlpp11](https://github.com/rbock/sqlpp11) for sql queries. And the table description is

```
CREATE TABLE `user_sms`(
`id` BIGINT(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`sender_number` VARCHAR(20),
`text` VARCHAR(2000),
`incoming_time` TIMESTAMP,
`created_at` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`users_user_id` BIGINT(30),
PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
FOREIGN KEY(`users_user_id`) REFERENCES `users`(`user_id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Encrypted cyphertext is bytes, not characters.  If you want it as characters then convert it to Base64 for transmission.   Attempts to read raw bytes directly as characters will fail for many possible reasons.

Comment: We need to see more of the code. I'm guessing `T` is a `std::string`. We need to see how your are creating the `string` from the `BLOB`. You could add an assert to the function: `ASSERT(encryptedText.size() % AES::BLOCKSIZE == 0)`. But its telling you what the exception has already told you.

Comment: @jww : Yes, `T` is of `std::string` type.

Comment: Show your SQL queries. Also see [How to INSERT binary std::string into BLOB](http://stackoverflow.com/q/733262/608639).

Comment: @jww : I have edited the question with sql queries.

Comment: I cannot imagine why you have made this a template. Plaintext is necessarily interpreted by any cipher algorithm as octets, i.e. C++ `char[]` or `unsigned char[]`, and ciphertext is certainly octets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Change the data type of array `key` and 'iv`from`byte`to`unsigned char`
- Change the `text` type in `mysql` database table `user_sms` from `VARCHAR` to `BLOB`.

`` CREATE TABLE `user_sms`(
 // Changes below is the changes has been made. 
`text` BLOB,
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; ``

Thanks [jww](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608639/jww) for help.